# Proving a Special Case of a Limit Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

I'm having trouble proving a special case of the limit theorem below. I attempted a proof by contradiction that appears to me to make sense in the first direction but I'm not able to come up with anything concrete for the reverse direction.

**Theorem:** *Let $a$ be an extended real number, and let $I$ be a nondegenerate open interval which either contains $a$ or has $a$ as one of its endpoints. Suppose further that $f$ is a real function defined on $I$ except possibly at $a$. Then*

$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x), x\in I$$

*exists and equals $L$ if and only if $f(x_n)\to L$ for all sequences $x_n\in I$ which satisfy $x_n \ne a$ and $x_n\to a$ as $n\to \infty$.*

**Special Case:** Suppose that $f:[a,\infty)\to \mathbb R$ for some $a\in \mathbb R$. Then $f(x)\to L$ as $x\in \infty$ if and only if $f(x_n)\to L$ for any sequence $x_n\in (a,\infty)$ which converges to $\infty$ as $n\to \infty$.

**My Attempt:**
$(\leftarrow)$ Assume $f(x_n)\to \infty$. For all sequences $x_n\to a$ as $n\to \infty$ but $f(x)$ does not go to $\infty$ as $x\to a$.

So, were looking for the negation of $\forall M\in \mathbb R, \exists \delta \gt 0$ such that $\forall x$ such that $0\lt |x-a|\lt \delta \Rightarrow f(x)\gt M$. Which is: $\exists M_0 \in \mathbb R$ such that $\forall \delta = \frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb N, \exists x_n \in I\setminus\{a\}$ such that $0\lt |x_n-a|\lt \frac{1}{n}$ and $f(x_n)\le M_0$.

Which means there is at least one sequence $\{x_n\}$ which converges to $a$, but $f(x_n)$ does not go to $\infty$. A contradiction to the first assumption.

Is this appropriate for the first part? If so, any help on how to go about the $(\rightarrow)$ direction would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I give the proof of the second part. may it be helpful for you!

**$(\rightarrow)$ direction:**

For any $\epsilon>0$, since $f(x)\to L$ as $x\to \infty$, then it means that there exists $M>0$, such that when $x> M$, $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. Now notice that $x_n\to \infty (n\to \infty)$, so there exists $N>0$ such that when $n>N$, $|x_n-M|>0$, and hence $|f(x_n)-L|<\epsilon$, which shows that $f(x_n)\to L$ for the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to $\infty$.

Comment: Does this follow with the theme of a proof by contradiction? Or, are you allowed to prove each direction by different methods?

Comment: No, it is not a proof by contradiction.

Comment: Are you allowed to prove one direction by contradiction and the other by direct proof? Or, do they both need to use the same method?

Comment: The proofs of two directions are two things.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Still not that experienced with proofs and what is and isn't allowed.

Comment: You are welcome!